# MSBuild ReadLinesFromFile Task Output attributes

Tags: msbuild, documentation

I want to learn how to use MSBuild [ReadLinesFromFile Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I observe `Output` tag in MSDN example.
In my project I also have `Output/@PropertyName` attribute.

I don't have an idea which other attributes `Output` tag can accept.
Where can I find description of them?

I suppose I should see some inherited tasks or something like this.
Where it is?  (I followed the links in the MSDN page, but it seems I missed something)
I don't know MSBuild in depth and I don't think I need it for my purposes, just want to find clear description of [ReadLinesFromFile Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe only stating the obvious, the task only accepts (well by documentation anyway) the `Lines` output parameter, as documented, and shown in an example, on the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you have linked in your question.

The "most clear" description you will find about the task is indeed the MSDN page.

BTW, looking inside `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll`, the `ReadLinesFromFile` task indeed only accepts the `Lines` output parameter.

Comment: Thanks, good idea to see inside Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll . It seems I missed to read about output elements http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164287.aspx